# Как из uint8 сделать QIcon?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

У меня есть переменная типа uint8*, которая "заполнена" картинкой. Как преобразовать её в QIcon? А вот функция, которая заполняет переменную типа uint8 картинкой - https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamUtils#GetImageRGBA

Comment: Через `QImage` потом `toPixmap`, потом `QIcon`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, согласен, полное имя конструктора `QImage(const uchar *data, int width, int height, Format format, QImageCleanupFunction cleanupFunction = Q_NULLPTR, void *cleanupInfo = Q_NULLPTR)`, читайте qt help по QImage

Comment: @PavelGridin можно через статику `QImage::fromData`, - чуть проще

Comment: один из аргументов функции  QImage::formData является int size. Что нужно передать в этот аргумент? sizeof () сойдет?

Comment: `Constructs a QImage from the first *size* bytes of the given binary *data*...`  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#fromData

Comment: @r1ddle-5, если имеете ввиду, `sizeof(uint8*)` , то это размер указателя, а вам нужен размер данных

Comment: да я уже разобрался как все сделать, вот только не могу понять что делать с вопросом

Comment: и спасибо вам за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала, попробуйте просто ее вывести, задав значение переменным width, height, buffer (ширина и высота должны быть равны количеству пикселей, умноженному на число байт к пикселю: обычно 3 для RGB и 4 для RGBA, попробуйте оба варианта). Получить QIcon можно преобразовав [QImage в QPixmap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#fromImage), далее можно просто использовать [конструктор](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#QIcon-1)...

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QImage>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QDialog *dialog = new QDialog();
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(dialog);

    int width;
    int height;
    unsigned char* buffer;

    QImage img(buffer, width, height, QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
    label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
    label->resize(width, height);

    dialog->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```